# Need tips on how to take care of my slightly browned basil plant

Tags: basil

My basil plant hasn't been doing well this winter and most of the stems have dried up so I snipped them off and now I recently cut my basil plant down completely because the remaining stems had been getting a bit brown and I put a plastic bag over it so it can be like a mini greenhouse but I am wondering if it will grow back?

Comment: Could you add a photo or two? You’ll likely get better answers if your fellow gardeners can *see* what you are talking about.

Comment: How long have you had the basil plant?